# Google Chrome Browser says Managed by your organization

Tags: windows, google-chrome, administrator

A few days ago I saw a message in Chrome saying `Managed by your organization`

[image]

Typing `about:policy` gives a policy name `ExtensionInstallSources` with no policy value.

https://support.google.com/chromebook/answer/1331549?p=is_chrome_managed&visit_id=636900475909824547-2816358712&rd=1

https://www.chromium.org/administrators/policy-list-3#ExtensionInstallSources

[image]

Is this due to the computer being linked to Active Directory or is there something else going on? Found a lot of threads popping up about this that seem to have the same policy name `ExtensionInstallSources` but no real reason why.

https://www.howtogeek.com/410106/why-does-chrome-say-its-managed-by-your-organization/

https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/3396218?hl=en

Comment: I have a similar problem but with another policy. In my case I used to have several extensions, but the ExtensionInstallSources  policy was not shown, only UserDataDir. Try deleting your userdata folder and see if the problem persists. I posted my question here https://superuser.com/questions/1425234/chrome-managed-by-your-organization-message-in-personal-computer

Answer (score 3):

**On Windows** you can try to disable "Managed by your organization" Chrome policies, by deleting the following registry entries (with `regedit` tool):

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Google\Chrome
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Policies\Google\Chrome
```

If that doesn't work, try to delete these Windows directories:

```
%WINDIR%\System32\GroupPolicy
%WINDIR%\System32\GroupPolicyUsers
```

**On Linux** you can remove Chrome policies by deleting the following directories (as `sudo`):

```
/etc/opt/chrome/policies
/etc/opt/chrome/policies/managed
/etc/opt/chrome/policies/recommended
```

See more info in this thread:
https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/3262871

Answer (score 2):

Here is a script to delete those keys from command line

```
reg delete HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Google\Chrome
reg delete HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Policies\Google\Chrome
reg delete HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Google\Chrome
reg delete HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Policies\Google\Chrome
reg delete HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Policies\Google\Update
reg delete HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\WOW6432Node\Google\Enrollment
reg delete HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\WOW6432Node\Google\Update\ClientState\{430FD4D0-B729-4F61-AA34-91526481799D} /v CloudManagementEnrollmentToken
```

It will work after explorer is restarted, so either restart Windows, or kill explorer and run it again (control+shift+escape; File>"Run new task"; write explorer; check "create this task with administrative privileges")

[Source](https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/9844476) (Thanks [Oz Edri](https://superuser.com/users/396466/oz-edri))

Comment: Lovely. Was trying to flush out some browser hijacking issue for a relative, and `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Policies\Google\Chrome` was the one I missed. God speed and fuck malware.