# Chrome "Managed by your organization" message in personal computer

Tags: google-chrome

Since version 73 Google Chrome has added a feature that shows a message when some settings are managed by your organization ([change log](https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/7679408?hl=en#73)). However in my home PC, I still see this message.

I deleted my app data folder (C:\Users[User]\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome) and then uninstalled Chrome altogether, and even executed the .bat provided by a Google employee on the Chrome's support page ([forum page](https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/3262871?msgid=3283941)). However the message persists.

When inspecting the policies this is what I see:

[image: chrome://policy/]

The only active policy is **UserDataDir** and its value is my User Data folder. I am not sure if I should be concerned about this, and if not, why does a default value from Chrome trigger such message?

I googled and I cannot find any example of this policy applied by default after a clean installation.

Any help/insights would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe a "security software" changes settings, like installing a certificate or add-on?

Comment: Thanks @davidbaumann I haven't gotten any extension since the clean installation. By the value of the policy I'd say is the expected setting, otherwise I have no clue what can be changing it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, I was able to get rid of the message. In my case I had to to go to the registry:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Policies\Google\Chrome\
```

and delete the key `UserDataDir`. After reopening Chrome, I no longer see the warning.

Also I double checked through https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6208960 which says:

> Your current account, [***MY_EMAIL***], isn’t managed by an
>   administrator. The account isn’t associated with any company, school,
>   or group. Instead, it’s a free Google Account that you can manage
>   yourself.

Hope it can help anyone.

Answer (score 1):

If previous answer didn't work for you, try to delete these **Windows** directories as well:

```
%WINDIR%\System32\GroupPolicy
%WINDIR%\System32\GroupPolicyUsers
```

**On Linux**, you can get rid of "Managed by your organization" Chrome policies, by removing these directories:

```
/etc/opt/chrome/policies
/etc/opt/chrome/policies/managed
/etc/opt/chrome/policies/recommended
```