# google chrome "managed by your organization" on linux

Tags: linux, google-chrome, security, malware, redhat-enterprise-linux

today I opened google chrome and saw this on customize and Control menu : "managed by your organization" , is that a malware sign ? if yes how can I completely remove that malware?
my os is a Linux RHEL distributions.

Comment: @InquisitiveLurker My chrome Version is  75.0.3770.80 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Comment: (I've deleted my previous comments, because I just realized I'd slightly misremembered things.)

Comment: Have you recently updated Chrome from an old (pre-73) version? In April, Chrome 73 introduced a change in behaviour which caused this message to [suddenly appear to a lot of people, seemingly for no reason](https://techdows.com/2019/04/chrome-managed-by-your-organization-message-in-menu.html). Apparently, since 73, the "managed by your organization" message can now also be triggered by various browser policies introduced by extensions or other applications (e.g. LastPass or antivirus programs).

Comment: In my case, it was actually an old empty key in my Windows registry, which triggered the behaviour after Chrome update (same one as in [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/1425234/chrome-managed-by-your-organization-message-in-personal-computer?noredirect=1&lq=1), if I remember correctly). Deleting it solved the issue. But since you are on Linux, it's going to be something else. I'd suggest starting with the article I linked.

Comment: @InquisitiveLurker No but I updated my os to a newer version recently

Comment: That might do it, I suppose. Either the OS upgrade also updated Chrome, or it might have added something else that triggered the message. Sorry I can't help you more, but like I said, I only have experience with this on the Windows side. Hopefully I've at least pointed you in the right direction. Good luck.

Answer (score 9):

It could be because of LastPass.

Please check if you have `lastpass-policy.json` at

```
/etc/opt/chrome/policies/managed/
```

or

```
/etc/chromium/policies/managed/
```

Deleting it, solves the problem.

Ref:

https://community.brave.com/t/your-browser-is-managed-by-your-organization/69676/12

https://www.reddit.com/r/chrome/comments/b7kqc0/chrome_is_managed_by_an_organization/