# Chrome "Managed by your organisation" appearing on personal macOS laptop

Tags: macos, google-chrome

> Same question, but for Windows (not a duplicate): [Chrome "Managed by your organization" message in personal computer](https://superuser.com/questions/1425234/chrome-managed-by-your-organization-message-in-personal-computer)

I noticed the "Managed by your organisation" message appear a while ago on my work MacBook Pro, provided by my employer. But now I'm seeing the same message appear on my personal MacBook Pro, which I bought myself directly from Apple. Why?

[image]

I'm signed into Chrome with the same personal Gmail account on both my work and personal laptops, so I'm worrying that this might have somehow given my employer access to 'manage' Chrome on my personal laptop too?

Here's my `chrome://policy/` screen - I can't see anything that suggests an organisation is managing it:

[image]

Comment: [ExtensionInstallSources](https://cloud.google.com/docs/chrome-enterprise/policies/?policy=ExtensionInstallSources) is an Enterprise Policy. The solution would likely be to not use the same gmail account for Chrome login on both work and personal laptops. Talk to an administrator at work.

Comment: But it's a personal Gmail address. Are you saying that if I log into Chrome on my work laptop with a personal account (something just about everyone does), Google automatically grants my employer permission to install policies into _any other computer_ that I log into later, without even prompting to check if this is what I want? Seems very unlikely. What if I logged into Chrome on two laptops managed by separate employers, could these companies then add/remove policies on each other's hardware? Doesn't make sense.

Comment: @callum I wonder if you edit the [chrome .plist file](https://www.chromium.org/administrators/mac-quick-start) and remove the applicable setting related to `UserDataDir` as per the "not a duplicate" link if that'd take care of it. I wonder if there's a way to wipre the .plist file entirely and start over with a default config. I don't have a lot of time to dig into it real deep right now, but wanted to mention to you for a potential starting point which might help. The MacOS will use .plist files for the chrome configuration though I believe so check it for applicable settings or to wipe.

Comment: What do you see in `chrome://management`? Did you try in Chrome to do Reset Settings, three-points menu *Settings > Advanced* on the bottom?

Comment: "Managed by your organization" just means that there are policies set. However this does not mean the policy has been applied by the company you work in. It can just mean that one application you installed has added a chrome policy.

Comment: @callum: Please answer our above comments.

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out by @user187561, the reason your Chrome browser is saying "Managed by your organisation" is because you (or software running on your system), has defined a [Google Chrome Enterprise Policy](https://cloud.google.com/docs/chrome-enterprise/policies/) and in particular, it looks like you've defined the [ExtensionInstallSources](https://cloud.google.com/docs/chrome-enterprise/policies/?policy=ExtensionInstallSources) policy to allow the installation of userscripts from github gists or userscripts.org.

The command that was run, by either you or software running on your system, was:
`defaults write com.google.Chrome ExtensionInstallSources -array "https://gist.githubusercontent.com/" "http://userscripts.org/*"`

If you didn't run this manually, it is difficult to know what triggered its execution, but I have found several setup scripts strewn about that do indeed have this line in it [example 1](https://gist.github.com/rands0n/5b8fe3fcdf6aa01a0e90), [example 2](https://github.com/donnemartin/dev-setup/blob/7f81c58ead6bf9a5f714e73bd1296b865d08ff57/osx.sh), [example 3](https://gist.github.com/justsml/f76fc9e751f76cc1074a9dcadac146bc).

Personally, I find it unlikely this was run purposely by your employer, as it arguably *reduces* security, but perhaps it is run by software that you've installed on both the work laptop and your personal machine.

You should be able to remove the policy, which should also get rid of the message and restore default behavior, by executing:
`defaults delete com.google.Chrome ExtensionInstallSources`