# Random Policy of Chrome reappearing even after deleting from registry

Tags: google-chrome, windows-registry

I am getting "managed by organisation" on Chrome on a personal Windows machine. And in `chrome://extensions` there are no malicious extensions.

[image: pic]

[image: pic]

The above image is of `Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Google\Chrome\ExtensionInstallForcelist`.

Whenever I delete and restart Chrome it stops saying managed by organisation. But when I restart PC the same problem comes back and the registry has the chrome policy just as it was before I had deleted it.

And there is no Google folder in `Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Policies`.

The following screenshot is of `chrome://policy`:
[image: pic]

I do not have AVG Antivirus installed which I read on many forums could be a possible cause for this. However, I did have some malware which was causing chrome to use 90% CPU in the background. After a scan using Malwarebytes, that issue has been resolved. However, Chrome still says that it is managed by an organisation. Since the policy has no value set, should I be concerned of it harming my computer?

Is the only way to clear the Windows registry of this policy to reset my PC?

Comment: Eliminating the malware will not reset anything it did to settings - see https://superuser.com/questions/1425234/chrome-managed-by-your-organization-message-in-personal-computer

Comment: But since there is no Policy value and no key in the registry, is the Malware even present anymore?